# Confused regarding .dir-locals.el and projectile

Tags: python, projectile

I have a `python` project, it has tests and I can execute them from the command line. I just read about `.dir-locals.el` in the `projectile` documentation and I want to execute tests from inside emacs using `projectile`.

So I create a `.dir-locals.el` file like:

```
((nil .
      (
       (projectile-project-test-cmd . "pytest --color=no")
       )))
```

The variable is set, but when do `C-c p P` (or `M-x projectile-test-project`) It asks for the command with `Test command:` (If I type there `pytest --color=no`, it will execute perfectly)

The documentation says that it is possible  to avoid the question setting the variable `compilation-read-command` to no nil.

```
((nil .
      ((compilation-read-command . nil)
       (projectile-project-test-cmd . "pytest --color=no")
       )))
```

But if I do that, `C-c p P` stops asking, but it doesn't execute the tests, it executes a `Compilation` (!)

This is the result:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/tmp/tsp/" -*-
Compilation started at Sat Oct 31 02:05:42



Compilation finished at Sat Oct 31 02:05:42
```

Would you mind to point me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docstring of [projectile-test-command](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/d1daf274e8ca2eb0f20475b8f314bb955167c6a1/projectile.el#L4007-L4011), this function first check `projectile-test-cmd-map` for the last command. It is likely you inadvertently invoked an empty `""` command in that emacs session, and that empty command was stored inside the hash-table. The problem will probably disappear when you restart emacs or invoke `(clrhash projectile-test-cmd-map)` to clear the hash-table.

It's worth mentioning though, according to the doc, `compilation-read-command` maybe risky if used as a file-local variable. So I'm not sure if it's a good idea to put this in your `.dir-locals.el`. Perhaps it's better to set it globally (or set inside emacs customization interface).