# Adding directory local variable for projectile test command is not working

Tags: projectile, directory-local-variables

I'm setting up my python lsp using this video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPXIP46BnNA&t=2435s).

My emacs init.el configuration file is [here](https://gist.github.com/rajcspsg/b2de69824a1efd2ce754602daf40f4b7)

By default `projectile-project-test-cmd` runs the command `python -m unittest discover`. I want to change it to `pytest` instead as explained by tutor.

I followed the below steps -

```
1. M-x add-dir-local-variable RET
2. choose mode 'python-mode'
3. Add local-variable 'projectile-project-test-cmd'.
4. Add local variable value "pytest".
```

It creates .dir-locals.el file with below contents -

```
((python-mode . ((projectile-project-test-cmd . "pytest"))))
```

Now when I run `M-x projectile-test-project` it runs pytest command.

But when I close emacs and reopen it, it stops running pytest and runs `python -m unittest discover` instead.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you in a file-visiting buffer when you run the command?  `dir-locals` don't affect other buffers automatically (i.e. the major mode needs to support the behaviour explicitly).

Comment: I don't work with python, but `python -m unittest discover` seems like a very specific command.  Where does that come from?  Perhaps your project is already setting this command in some other way, taking precedence over your dir-local value.

Comment: What's the output of `(gethash (projectile-compilation-dir) projectile-test-cmd-map)`? Related maybe? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61493/confused-regarding-dir-locals-el-and-projectile/61594#61594

Answer (score 2):

Did you save the .dir-locals.el file? Are you loading these files via TRAMP?  By default, Emacs doesn't look for the .dir-locals.el file when loading files via TRAMP, as it might add significant delays. If this is the problem, you can set `enable-remote-dir-locals` to `t` to opt in.

Comment: Yes I saved the file in the project root. Also I'm not loading it via tramp

Comment: Test with emacs -Q to see if it sets that variable when you open the file. If it works there, perhaps some part of your Emacs config is incorrect.